# How can I move one disk partition so I can expand the original one?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

The image below helps to explain what I mean. I have one physical SD disk that currently contains 5 partitions. I want to get rid of the partition **F** and use its space to expand the **C** partition. I am unable to do that with the Windows 10 Disk Management because the F partition is not right-next-to-it.

So it seems the solution is moving the -Recovery Partition- after the F but I have no clue how that can be accomplished and if my logical thinking using this approach makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it should be doable but you may have to use 3rd party tools.

Comment: @ChanganAuto is correct. Windows native tools does not allow backwards expansion. For a free tool, MiniTool and EaseUS are capable of this.

Comment: thanks I will check it out, if you guys trust a paid tool as well that you find reliable please share with me as well

Comment: See my answer for what you need to do. There are good free partition editors, as recommended above.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the partition F. The problem will be that when it becomes
Unallocated space, this space follows the Windows Recovery partition.
You will need to move it after C to be able to expand it.

You can't move Unallocated space, so you need to do it this way:

- Create boot media for a third-party partition editor
- Boot the partition editor from the boot media and use it to:

  - Delete the partition F
  - Move the Windows Recovery partition to the end of the disk
- Boot back into Windows and use Disk Management to extend C.

I suggest taking careful backups before starting the operation,
because an error may cost you the disk.